# How to View the messages of a batch file which is run from another batch file on command prompt screen?

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have a batch script : script1.bat(master script). 
I call another batch script from within script1.bat say script2.bat.

When i execute script1.bat it calls script2.bat and everything perfectly works fine.

My problem is I am not able to view the echo commands embedded inside script2.bat on the command prompt screen when I execute script1.bat.

So what command should I use to get the messages inside script2.bat to display on the command prompt window?

Comment: How about you show us the code you are using.  None of us are omniscient.

Comment: Script 1.bat :
echo This is script1
call .\Script2.bat

Script2.bat :
Echo Changing the directory
cd ..\SqlServer
echo Configuration Completed
goto Exit
:Exit

I will be executing script1.bat.

What is see in the screen is  :

This is script1

My requirement is that I should get the following output:

This is script1
Configuration Completed

Answer (score 0):

You could export everything happening in script2.bat with

```
echo something >file.dat
```

Remember that > will overwrite any data and start from new while >> will add on to the file.

You can then get script1.bat to "type file.dat" with a timeout on it or a ping delay.

Comment: Thank you Nizon.

Type is displaying the complete contents of the file. I don't want to do that. I just want few of the messages to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: You dont have to export everything, you could just export a few things to file.dat and then clean it or export to a new file?